# Not getting JSON data when using AJAX, Slim and PHP

Tags: php, api, slim

I am learning to create Rest API using Slim, but got stuck in here. I tried many things mentioned on internet but its still not getting value.

My Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pages/search',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {'val1':value1,'val2':value2},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.val1);
        }
    });
```

My PHP using Slim:

```
<?php

require 'Slim/Slim.php';

$app = new Slim();

$app->post('/search','getValue');
$app->run();


function getValue(){
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $values= json_decode($request->getBody());

    $value1 = $values->val1;    // Throwing error here - Slim Application Error
    $value2 = $values->val2;

    echo "{'val1':'".$value1."'}";

}

?>
```

Comment: Where is your variable `$values` assign?

Comment: check your browser console window for the exact error you are getting.

Comment: @FatalError Sorry I just updated it.

Comment: @AmanRawat Similar like this coming http://generaria.com/evento/ficha/24 I just encountered this while searching

Comment: try to debug by echo $request->getBody();exit; and check the output for the same

Comment: @AmanRawat this is coming 'val1=sad&val2=fa' values are coming right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to read a JSON formatted request:

```
$values= json_decode($request->getBody());
```

and then outputting **invalid** JSON as the response (probably with the default `Content-Type: text/html` response header).

But you are passing jQuery's `data` a plain object so you are making a standard **form encoded** request:

```
data: {'val1':value1,'val2':value2},
```

and you are forcing jQuery to treat the response as JSON (which it isn't):

```
dataType: "json",
```

---

Assuming you want to make a JSON request and respond with JSON you need to:

### Format the request correctly:

```
data: JSON.stringify( { val1: value1, val2: value2} ),
contentType: "application/json",
```

### Output the response correctly:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode( array( "val1" => $value1 ) );
```

(NB: I have no idea what PHP framework you are using. The header function might not be the right way to deal with setting response headers in it).

Comment: yeah this just solved. I didn't make JSON right. Now its working. Tons of thanks. :)